# Rotating around a point, object consistently getting further

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm making a game in Unity, and need an enemy to rotate around a point. I'm using atan2 to get the direction to the point, adding 90 degrees and then using cos and sin to change the position. After finding the object does rotate, but get further from the point, I decided to try this out in p5js. However I get the same issue.
Here is the code:

```js
let x = 100;
let y = 100;
let speed = 5

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  let dir = atan2(y - height / 2, x - width / 2);
  x += cos(dir + 90) * speed;
  y += sin(dir + 90) * speed;
  rect(x, y, 20, 20);
  console.log(dir)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So which is it, javascript or C#

Comment: There's no question in the post. Did you mean to ask how to rotate one position around another position in unity? The logic doesn't work because you're moving `speed` units in the direction of a tangent on the circle, but that doesn't describe circular motion. Basically the same problem addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403553/1092820). You would need to take a different approach.

Comment: It's both. I initially made this in unity then went to see if i get the same result with js, but I see that the problem is in my method. How would i go about doing this, would it be better to get current coordinates, convert to polar and adjust the theta then convert back to cartesian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but get further from the point [...]

Of course. You don't move on a circle. You move along the tangent of the circle. Each step on the tangent increases the distance from the center of the circle. Hence the distance to the center increase in each frame.

You can easily check this by scaling the distance vector with the ratio of the original distance and the current distance:

```js
let x = 100;
let y = 100;
let speed = 5
let dist;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
    angleMode(DEGREES)
    dist = sqrt(pow(y - height/2, 2) + pow(x - width/2, 2));
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    let dir = atan2(y - height / 2, x - width / 2);
    x += cos(dir + 90) * speed;
    y += sin(dir + 90) * speed;
    
    let newDist = sqrt(pow(y - height/2, 2) + pow(x - width/2, 2));
    x = (x - width/2) * dist/newDist + width/2
    y = (y - height/2) * dist/newDist + height/2
    
    rect(x, y, 20, 20);
    console.log(dir)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @matidfk This is an option. Actually, I did not present a solution, I just pointed out the issue.

Comment: Which one do you think would be better in terms of performace, since your bit of code works, but uses a lot of squares/square roots, whereas mine uses sin and cos instead.